# Ubuntu 18.04 sound suddenly stopped working

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus

After rebooting my Asus ROG Strix Ubuntu 18.04 laptop today, sound no longer works - but has been working fine for over 6 months now!

I have installed and run `pavucontrol` and when I go to `Output Devices` and select `HeadPhones (unplugged)` then reselect `Speakers`, I *DO* get sound - but only for a few seconds.

[image: pavucontrol reviving sound for a few seconds]
After a few seconds have elapsed, there is an ugly "fade-out" like thing (not exactly volume-down, but also weird low-pass filter applied), and then I get nothing.

If I repeat the above process immediately, I also don't get no sound. If I wait a few more seconds, then I do get sound back but only for very little time.

I can't imagine this is a hardware issue, since I have dual-boot Windows 10, and on Windows side sound has kept on working correctly!

Plugging headphones or external speakers doesn't help at all.

I have read about removing `pulseaudio` and going for `alsa` drivers here: https://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/
but I am afraid of screwing things up further when this might be a tiny stupid issue.

I've also read about the sound chip overheating, which is again weird since Windows side is OK(?): [Identify element requesting sound chip to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912848/identify-element-requesting-sound-chip-to-sleep/912879#912879)

Comment: To make your speakers as your default output: https://askubuntu.com/a/1207638/1550967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For now**, problem seems to have gone away after following *some* instructions from here: [No sound from speakers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067195/no-sound-from-speakers-on-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1)

Actually, I've done `sudo alsamixer`, fiddle a bit with it and... now it's working; when tens of reboots wouldn't help a tad.

Comment: So frustrating, have same issue on new install of 19, a short (seconds) amount of audio works (but only from firefox) then tails off and no longer works. If the pavc window is open it never works. No amount of tweeking alsamixer has fixed. If I wait ten seconds without changing anything it works briefly again