# Sound stops working when computer goes to sleep?

Tags: sound, 20.04, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

So I'm using Kubuntu at the moment and everything has been super nice so far, but I do have one major problem... For some reason, whenever the laptop goes to sleep, the audio completely stops working and the only thing I can see in the audio manager device wise is "dummy audio". Restarting the machine fixes it, but only for a while because as soon as it goes back to sleep the audio stops working again.

Solutions I've tried:
[Ubuntu 18.04 sound suddenly stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134282/ubuntu-18-04-sound-suddenly-stopped-working)

Doing `sudo alsa force-reload` does nothing for me, and using the command `alsaloop` gives me this error:

```
playback hw:0,0 open error: No such file or directory
Loopback initialization failure.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.